# why salt.modules.schedule does not work?

Tags: salt-stack

I ran this command on salt-master:

`salt "*" schedule.add job1 function='test.ping' seconds=1`

and just for sure ran this command too:

`salt "*" schedule.list`

and saw that the job is added.

but when I ran:

`salt "*" saltutil.running`

does not show any running job while I expect to see some `test.ping jobs`.

so what is wrong? I am missing something or this module are not working correctly?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually you did nothing wrong and the job is running fine.

Take a look at Salts event bus `salt-run state.event pretty=True`, and you'll see the execution and results of test.ping from each minion.

For example:

```
salt/job/20170524120921759930/ret/minoin_A {
    "_stamp": "2017-05-24T09:09:21.762697",
    "arg": [],
    "cmd": "_return",
    "fun": "test.ping",
    "fun_args": [],
    "id": "minion_A",
    "jid": "20170524120921759930",
    "pid": 17689,
    "return": true,
    "schedule": "job1",
    "success": true,
    "tgt": "minion_A",
    "tgt_type": "glob"
}
```

My guess is `saltutil.running` isn't showing anything because `test.ping` finishes very fast, or maybe `saltutil.running` is ignoring schedule jobs.